# How to get AD user that does not have Picture

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to get a list of AD user who does not have picture. I am on QBC.CAN domain and trying to get information from KOBAL domain. The KOBAL domain looks like this KOBAL.COM. There is OU called SALES AND sub OU called NORTHWEST.

My job is the get a list of users with name, title, email, where Picture is not present. thumbnailPhoto is the ldap-display name. I tried few queries but it doesn't give me what I need and keep getting error.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Server "ADCP12WSDC54X01.KOBAL.COM" -properties thumbnailPhoto | ? {!$_.thumbnailPhoto} | select Name
```

This code works but I don't need the entire list. I only need OU=SALES,OU=NORTHWEST. If I change the script to following I get an error

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=NORTHWEST, OU=SALES ,DC=KOBAL,DC=COM" -properties thumbnailPhoto | ? {!$_.thumbnailPhoto} | select Name

Get-ADUser : The supplied distinguishedName must belong to one of the following
 partition(s): 'DC=QBC,DC=CAN , CN=Configuration,DC=QBC,DC=CAN , cN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=QBC,DC=CAN , DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=QBC,DC=CAN, DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=QBC,DC=CAN'.
```

Comment: Distinguished names are very sensitive.  They need to appear *exactly* as they do in the objects.  Here, it should probably be `"OU=NORTHWEST,OU=SALES,DC=KOBAL,DC=COM"`.  Also, your `Where-Object` should probably be testing `$_.thumbnailPhoto -ne $null`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it looks like it now switching to kobal.com domain controller. I get the same error that I posted. any other ideas. I can use -server syntax but I am not sure how to pass the exact OU if I use -server syntax.

Comment: I used same syntax with QBC.can and it works. I can navigate to kobal.com using AD user and computer UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I would use:

```
$SearchBase = 'OU=NORTHWEST,OU=SALES,DC=KOBAL,DC=COM';
$LdapServer = 'YourLDAPServerName';

$UsersWithoutPhotos = Get-ADUser -Filter 'thumbnailPhoto -notlike "*"' -SearchBase $SearchBase -SearchScope 'Subtree' -Server $LdapServer | Select-Object 'Name'
```

The filter here removes the need for piping to a `Where-Object`.  It will return any user in the target OU or below that doesn't have a thumbnailPhoto attribute.  You don't need `-Properties thumbnailPhoto` now since you're not using it for anything anymore, so you won't be returning all that data.

---

Edit to add:

By default, the only properties returned by `Get-ADUser` are DistinguishedName, Enabled, GivenName, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID, Surname, UserPrincipalName.  If you want access to anything else, you'll need to include the `-Properties` parameter again with `Get-ADUser` to tell that command to fetch that data, too.  All the `Select-Object` command does is eliminate fields that you don't want to see.

This should work for you:

```
$UsersWithoutPhotos = Get-ADUser -Filter 'thumbnailPhoto -notlike "*"' -SearchBase $SearchBase -SearchScope 'Subtree' -Server $LdapServer -Properties 'title', 'displayName';
```

You can then restrict it to just the fields you want:

```
$UsersWithoutPhotos = $UsersWithoutPhotos | Select-Object 'Name','title', 'displayName';
```

Or sort it by a field:

```
$UsersWithoutPhotos = $UsersWithoutPhotos | Sort-Object 'displayName';
```

And display it:

```
$UsersWithoutPhotos | Format-Table -AutoSize;
```

Or:

```
$UsersWithoutPhotos | Out-GridView;
```

Of course, you can do all that on one line, too, and just keep piping.

Comment: Works ppPerfectly. Is there a way to better format the output? and add additional user attributes to output?

Comment: Sure, it all depends on what you're looking for.  I simply used `Select-Object 'Name'` because that's what you used.

Comment: Select-Object 'Name','displayName','title' only gives me name. I tried without the quotation with comma and same thing. any idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I added explanation above.

Comment: GREAT. THANKS Bacon Bits. Perfect. Works like a charm. I appreciate your help and patience with me.

Comment: I added this to export the list. $UsersWithoutPhotos  | export-csv -path "c:\UsersWOPic.csv"

Comment: Excellent.  You might want to use `Export-Csv -Path "c:\UsersWOPic.csv" -NoTypeInformation`. That will get rid of that `#TYPE Selected.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser` or similar crap on the first line.

Comment: Bacon: you are too generous. This script helped me as well. Good question ST.